# Creating an array of possible string variations

Tags: string, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to figure out how I would create variations of a string, by replacing one character at a time in the string with a different character from another array.

For example:

> variations = "abc"
>
> getVariations "xyz" variations

Should return:

> ["xbc", "ybc", "zbc", "axc", "ayc", "azc", "abx", "aby", "abz"]

I'm not quite sure how to go about this. I tried iterating through the string, and then using list comprehension to add the possible characters but I end up losing characters.

```
[c ++ xs | c <- splitOn "" variations]
```

Where xs is the tail of the string.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively you can define `getVariations replacements input`

- if `input` is empty, the result is ...
- if `input` is `(a:as)`, combine the results of:

  1. replacing `a` with a character from `replacements`
  2. keeping `a` the same and performing `getVariations` on `as`

This means the definition of `getVariations` could look ike:

```
getVariations replacements []  = ...
getVariations replacements (a:as) = ...#1... ++ ...#2...
```

It might also help to decide what the type of `getVariations` is:

```
getVariations :: String -> String -> ???
```